# How to configure socket.io sticky session on bluemix

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I need to deploy a socket.io application on IBM Bluemix with multiple cloudfoundry instances to ensure load balancing.

I followed socket.io documentation and this [link](https://github.com/rajaraodv/redispubsub) to use sticky session and to be sure each socket goes to the correct instance.

Unfortunately, my client is disconnected just after connect event and error '400 xhr poll' error is fired.

Here is my server code :

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const redis = require('redis')
const app = require('express')()
const http = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(http)
const RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session)
const redisUrl = 'myredis'

var session = session({
  store: new RedisStore({client: client}),
  secret: 'mysecret',
  name: 'jsessionid',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
})

app.use(cookieParser)
app.use(session)

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('a user is connected')

  socket.on('testPing', function () {
      socket.emit('testPong', {})
  })
})


http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log('listening on *:' + (process.env.PORT || 3000))
})
```

after several hours searching on Google, I don't know what to try anymore. I really need some help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code in the question has jsessionid lowercase. Have you tried uppercasing it?

Comment: Nice ! Thank you Chris, it works perfectly now!

Comment: Cool.  I’ve added this as an answer.  Would you mind accepting and up voting?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a lower case `jsessionid`.  Try uppercasing it.  The docs on sessions are here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#sessions

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently (although without Redis), to fix the same issue; socket.io and load balancers don't play well together out of the box. The key is to use a JSESSIONID cookie, for session affinity. This was my code:

```
const expressSession = require('express-session');
```

...

```
var app = express();
```

...

```
app.use(
    expressSession({
      key: 'JSESSIONID', // use a sticky session to make sockets work
      secret: 'arbitrary-secret',
      cookie: {
         maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 day
         secure: false
      },
      saveUninitialized: false,
      resave: false
   })
);
//setting up socket.io for realtime communication
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I've already try to set this cookie. It works fine with a single instance, but with several nodes instance my client is disconnected.

It's like Bluemix doesn't implements Cloud foundry affinity session ...

Comment: I've just tested on Pivotal my code and it doesn't work any more. I'm doing something wrong but I don't understand what ...